# Extract parts of file path and concatenate in bash

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and my dir structure looks like below.

"/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/2015/01/01"

I am trying to produce the output like this - "JKL_2015-01-01".

I am trying using sed and cut and might take a while but this is needed immediately and any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: please show us some code you have tried. we might correct errors.

Comment: Is it always /ABC/DEF/GHI/... then the directories you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i=/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/2015/01/01
o=`echo $i | sed -r 's|^.+/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$|\1_\2-\3-\4|'`
```

`i=xxx` is a variable assignment, no whitespace around `=` allowed!

```
`command`
```

enclosed by backticks is a command substitution, which captures the standard output of the command inside as a string.

And `sed` is the stream editor, applying mostly regex based operations to each line from standard input, and emitting the result on standard output.

sed's `s|||` operation is regex based substitution. I capture 4 character groups with parens `()`: (non-slashes), slash, (numbers), slash, (numbers), slash, (numbers), end-of-string `$`. Then in the second part of the subst I print the for captured groups, separated by an underscore and 2 dashes, respectively.

Comment: `echo $i` isn't necessarily reliable -- if we have content that contains a whitespace-surrounded wildcard, for instance, that wildcard will be expanded; similarly, strings of characters inside `IFS` will be condensed to a single space. Much safer to write `sed ... <<<"$i"`, or `printf '%s\n' "$i" | ...`, or, at the very minimum, `echo "$i" | ...`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what i needed. Just to understand, what part of this code eliminates the "/ABC/DEF/GHI/" from the file path? 

Also, do I need to use numbers or the following also works? 

sed -r 's|^.+/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$|\1_\2-\3-\4|'

Comment: Also, what does "-r" option in sed used for?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The `-r` option enables the extended regex engine, with `+` for one or more, parens for capture groups don't need backslashes, etc. AFAIK, it's a GNU-only option (not on BSD).

Comment: As to what eliminates the 1st part of the string: The 1st capture group in parens is preceeded by `^.+/` in the search pattern. This part is not printed in the 2nd part of the `s///` expression.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use tools that aren't built into bash for this -- using builtins is far more efficient than external tools like `sed`.

```
s="/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/2015/01/01"
s_re='/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'
if [[ $s =~ $s_re ]]; then
  name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_${BASH_REMATCH[2]}-${BASH_REMATCH[3]}-${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
  echo "$name"
fi
```

Alternately, and perhaps more readably (using string manipulation techniques documented in [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100)):

```
s="/ABC/DEF/GHI/JKL/2015/01/01"
s_prefix=${s%/*/*/*/*}          # find the content we don't care about
s_suffix=${s#"$s_prefix"/}      # strip that content

# read the rest into named variables
IFS=/ read -r category year month day <<<"$s_suffix"

# assemble those named variables into the string we care about
echo "${category}_${year}-${month}-${day}"
```